# Custom NextMonth CallenderControll button bug

Tags: c#, asp.net

so i need to make a custom Next/prev button and i almost got it to work it jsut has a litle problem with displaying the right number in my label for some reason it shows the day before the one the callender is showing so if its December it would display 11th in the label i think its something with PostBack i just cant figure out what so after hours of frustration im gonna try and ask for help here this is what i have so far

**Source Code Backend**

```
private int Month;
private int Year;
private DateTime Date;

void DayRender(Object source, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    // Change the background color of the days in the month
    // to yellow.
    if (!e.Day.IsOtherMonth && !e.Day.IsWeekend)
        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;

    // Add custom text to cell in the Calendar control.
    if (e.Day.Date.Day == 18)
        e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />Holiday"));
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now;
        Calendrier.VisibleDate = Date;
        Month = Date.Month;
        Session["Month"] = Month;
        Year = Date.Year;
    }
    MonthLabel.Text = Session["Month"].ToString();
}
// when next button is being clicked
protected void NextMonth_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int SessionMonth;

    SessionMonth = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Month"]);
    SessionMonth++;
    Session["Month"] = SessionMonth;
    ChangeCallender(2000, SessionMonth);
}

// method to add Date to Callender
private void ChangeCallender(int year, int month)
{
    DateTime date = new DateTime(year , month, 1);
    Calendrier.VisibleDate = date;
}
```

Comment: `private`, `protected`....and `C` ? How?

Comment: oh dammit i mean C# must have made a  typo srry mate